# Как исправить PHP Notice: Undefined variable:

Tags: php

Как исправить ошибку с ранее не заданной переменной?

ошибку выдает такую

```
[Fri Nov 10 11:57:43.119277 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9266] [client 95.182.77.250:54116] AH01215: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: content in /var/www/***/data/www/***/account/notifications.php on line 285
```

В строке такой код

```
if (isset($content)) {$content = 0;}
```

Эту переменную задал выше в самом начале скрипта, таким образом:

```
$content = 0;
```

Все равно показывает ошибку...

Comment: вам пишут про переменную `count_notifi_transferlead` в файле `notifications.php` строка 288

Comment: перепутал, но смысл тот же

Comment: уж не внутри ли функции какой-нибудь находится эта ошибка?

Comment: в переменную $content записываются данные через цикл таким образом $content .= '...';

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev запустил на локалке ваш код: `error_reporting(-1);

$content = 0;

if (isset($content)) {
    $content = 0;
}` Нет никаких ошибок.